# External authentication/authorization for CakePHP

Tags: php, security, authentication, cakephp, single-sign-on

We are considering options for implementing a single sign-on for a few web applications, of which some are CakePHP (1.3) and others are not. I'm hoping for advice or comments from people who have done this before.

Here's the idea: Access to the CakePHP app is controlled by the server AuthType.  If the user isn't authenticated, they can't access the app at all, and instead get kicked back to the SSO login page. If they then login successfully, they are redirected back to the app and granted access by the web server.

At this point, CakePHP would read the contents of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to identify the user and present him or her with the correct information.

Specific questions:

- Assuming we can trust that the SSO is secure, is this approach safe and robust?
- Is it possible (or useful) to integrate this mechanism with Cake's Auth component?
- Is it Cakey to read the `$_SERVER` super-global directly?

  Is there a more Cake-like way of making an application SSO aware?

To clarify, I only need to know the authenticated user—I don't need (or want) to share the entire session with any other app.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Just to reiterate my comment below, the SSO and all the apps will be on our servers. We won't use RealID or any other external auth mechanism.  So when I say "external" auth, I mean external to CakePHP but not external to our web server.

Comment: If all components can be under the same domain (using subdomains, perhaps) and everything is written in PHP, you may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, REMOTE_USER is only set when the "Authorization Required" header is set and the user authenticates using http auth.

Most single sign on services use oAuth type tokens to log users in.  I don't think they will set the SERVER variable.

In either case, using http authentication isn't recommended, because it's not possible to log someone out if you notice suspicious activity.  And users can't log themselves out except by shutting the browser.

I'd recommend strongly that you stick with session based authentication and authorization.

Comment: The server's `REMOTE_USER` variable should be set for any server-based AuthType, not just http auth; at least, I have confirmed that it is set in my situation. The question of logging out is tricky with any SSO and I intentionally avoided it here. AFAIK, session-based auth isn't really an option for SSO across multiple apps built on different frameworks.

Comment: When you say SSO, do you mean "across my apps", or something like facebook connect?  I may have jumped the gun and assumed it was the latter -- in that case, I haven't seen that REMOTE_USER is set with requests (although it could just be that my server config is different).

Comment: The SSO and all the apps it works with will be on our servers. We have no interest in using any outside authentication source. The authentication takes place through a server extension (we're using pubcookie) that talks to the login server, so you can enable it by adding the appropriate AuthType to the .htaccess.  The server then sets `REMOTE_USER` just like it would for any other authentication.